# CVX : Obtaining the minimizing parameter at the optimum

Tags: convex-optimization, cvx

In CVX, how do we return the value of the parameter over which the problem is minimized at the optimal value?

By this, I mean, how do we obtain

$$x^* = \arg\min_x f(x)$$ when solving the problem with CVX?

I have gone through the user's guide and did some google searching. The only thing I could find was `cvx_optval` which only gives the optimal value of $f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just stored in the regular MATLAB variable x (or whatever you were using as the variable in your problem.

Comment: Ah. That simple is it? Stupid me :)